# How to insert values in XML database using XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery, sedna

I'm using native xml database Sedna system, and I don't fully understand it.
Is xQuery just for getting data and show it ?
or I can select, insert and update records (actually node's data or attributes).
if it is how can I do it using xQuery ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sedna provides simple proprietary updates language to manipulate data.

See there: [Update Language](http://www.sedna.org/progguide/ProgGuidesu6.html#x12-440002.3) for details and examples.

Let me know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 2):

XQuery "core" is read-only, but there is also a standardized XQuery Update Facility defined as an extension to the core language.

Because the Update spec was late in development, many XML database vendors anticipated it with their own proprietary update languages or XQuery extensions. I don't know what the situation is with Sedna.